# Php paging data count show up at each page

Tags: php

I want to show up paging data like Displaying 1 - 5 of 16 . I am trying to do this as below

```
    $nb_elem_per_page = 3;
    $page = isset($_GET['pg'])?intval($_GET['pg']):0;
    $data = $aawp_table['products'] ;
    $number_of_pages = ceil(count($data)/$nb_elem_per_page);
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $nb_elem_per_page;

Displaying <?php echo  $offset .' - '.$nb_elem_per_page .' of ' . count($data); ?>
```

But I am not getting proper result for this

Comment: What is the value of `$_GET['pg']` for the first and second page ? 0 and 1, or 1 and 2 ?

Comment: first - 0 second 1

Comment: You say you're not getting a proper result but what result are you getting for what inputs (and what result do you expect if different from 1-5 of 16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a negative value of `$offset` if `($page - 1)`.

You can juste remove it and it will work.

Code :

```
$nb_data = 20;
$nb_elem_per_page = 3;
$page = isset($_GET['pg']) ? intval($_GET['pg']) : 0;
$number_of_pages = ceil($nb_data / $nb_elem_per_page);
$offset = $page * $nb_elem_per_page;
echo  $offset .' - ' . $nb_elem_per_page .' of ' . $nb_data;
```

- If `pg` is not defined, the result will be `0 - 3 of 20`
- If `pg` is 0, the result will be `0 - 3 of 20`
- If `pg` is 1 , the result will be `3 - 3 of 20`
- And so on...

Note that you should test if `$page` is lower than `$number_of_pages` to avoid to go to far, or lower than 0.

**EDIT** A more complete code :

```
function run_pager($pg = null)
{
    $nb_data = 20;
    $nb_elem_per_page = 3;
    $number_of_pages = ceil($nb_data / $nb_elem_per_page);
    $page = isset($pg) ? intval($pg) : 0;
    if ($page < 0) $page = 0;
    if ($page >= $number_of_pages) $page = $number_of_pages - 1;
    $offset = $page * $nb_elem_per_page;
    $end = $offset + $nb_elem_per_page;
    if ($end > $nb_data) $end = $nb_data;
    return ($offset + 1) .' - ' . ($end) .' of ' . $nb_data;
}
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    echo "i=$i : " . run_pager($i) . PHP_EOL;    
}
```

Output :

```
i=0 : 1 - 3 of 20
i=1 : 4 - 6 of 20
i=2 : 7 - 9 of 20
i=3 : 10 - 12 of 20
i=4 : 13 - 15 of 20
i=5 : 16 - 18 of 20
i=6 : 19 - 20 of 20
```

Comment: echo  $offset .' - ' . $nb_elem_per_page .' of ' . $nb_data;  not incrementing $nb_elem_per_page value as this showing 0-3 next page 4-4. but next page should be 4-6

Comment: Look at this [demo](https://3v4l.org/PshnK).
Nb element per page is never changed; it's OK. Only offset is moving.

Comment: but this should work like 
i=0 : 1 - 3 of 20
i=1 : 4 - 6 of 20
i=2 : 7 - 9 of 20

Comment: I've updated the answer. See also the [demo](https://3v4l.org/DFpHp)